Can't Hover and Vertical Scroll The Topmost Container of The Title Tabs when Customizing Obsidian Notes
Sorry if my grammar is bad. I have the latest version (v1.6.7) of Obsidian Notes. I want to configure my Obsidian Notes to have multiple rows of title tabs. Below is my CSS script:
:root {
  --max-tab-rows: 4;
  /* Adjust this number to limit the number of rows*/
  --tab-height: 50px;
  /* Adjust this number to set the height of each tab*/
  --tab-width: 200px;
  /* Adjust this number to set the width of each tab*/
}

/* Container for the tab headers*/
.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container {
  /* z-index: 10000 !important; */
  display: flex !important;
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
  /* Enables vertical scrolling*/
  height: auto !important;
  max-height: calc(var(--tab-height) * var(--max-tab-rows)) !important;
  /* Limit the number of rows*/
}

/* Inner container for the tab headers*/
.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container-inner {
  /* z-index: 10000 !important; */
  flex-wrap: wrap !important;
  margin: unset !important;
  padding: unset !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow-y: auto !important;
}

/* Individual tab header*/
.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header {
  flex: 0 0 var(--tab-width) !important;
  /* Fixed width for each tab*/
  width: var(--tab-width) !important;
  max-width: var(--tab-width) !important;
  /* height: var(--tab-height) !important;*/
  /* Set height for each tab
  border: 1px solid var(--color-base-50) !important;
  /* Ensure border styling is visible*/
}

/* New tab button*/
.titlebar .workspace-tab-header-new-tab,
.mod-root .workspace-tab-header-new-tab {
  display: table-cell !important;
  padding: unset !important;
}

/* Hide the default tab list button*/
.titlebar .workspace-tab-header-tab-list,
.mod-root .workspace-tab-header-tab-list {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Ensures no extra margin for the last tab*/
.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-inner::after {
  width: 0px !important;
}

/* Remove tab outline color*/
body {
  --tab-outline-color: unset !important;
}

/*============ALL FOR THE SCROLLBARS=========*/

/* Hide the horizontal scrollbar*/
.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container-inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* z-index: 1000 !important; */
}

.workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  /* z-index: 1000 !important; */
  background-color: #555864;
  border-radius: 10px !important
}

.workspace-tab-header-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: brown;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #bbb !important;
}

/*===========================*/

.workspace-tab-header.tappable {
  border: 1px solid white !important;
  height: 25px !important;
}

/* .workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container-inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover { */
/*   background-color: black !important; */
/*   border-radius: 4px !important; */
/* } */

/* Firefox scrollbar styling*/
/* .workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container { */
/*   scrollbar-width: thin !important; */
/*   scrollbar-color: gray transparent !important; */
/* } */
/*  */
/* .workspace .mod-root .workspace-tab-header-container::-webkit-scrollbar-track { */
/*   background: transparent !important; */
/* } */

/*===================================*/

Here is the preview screenshot:
Preview screenshot of customized Obsidian Notes
The red encircled section is the "container of the title tabs". The scrollbar thumb in this section can't be scrolled vertically (top to bottom and vice versa). To ensure all the scrollbars and thumbs are affected by being edited (some of them cannot be edited while using a different theme), I added the following code:

::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
  background-color: #bbb !important;
}

Yes, all of them are affected when hovered, except in the container of the titles. I have adjusted the z-index of the scrollbar and its thumb to be 1000 to ensure that I can interact with it. However, this was not a good idea because when I opened the settings, it overlaps with the container, so I decided to comment it out.
Yes, you can say that my script is messed because I am not advanced in CSS, I'm only advanced in backend and database langauges. I don't know if it will become terrible if I resize the container of tabs horizontally (from left to right and vice versa). I tried this in Obsidian Notes Android and it behave almost correctly (I can scroll the container vertically: from top to bottom and vice versa).
To make it more clear, these are my intended purposes:

I can specify the width of each tab inside the container. The width will remain constant, even if there is only a single tab in a new row of the container. --tab-width
I can specify the height of the container (not the tabs inside the container). --container-height
You don't need to specify the maximum number of tabs in each row, as this is already determined by the minimum tab width.
When I resize the container horizontally, whether to the left or right, each title tab will maintain a constant width until the container reaches the initial width of --tab-width (e.g. 100px). At this point, the tabs cannot be resized to a smaller width.
You don't need to make the tabs fill 100% of the container width, as the container cannot be further reduced in size.
The container of the tabs can be scrolled vertically (from top to bottom and vice versa). This is the top priority, so ensure it functions correctly.

Can anyone help me fix this incorrect code?
